# React performance optimization

Tags: reactjs, optimization

Instead of using useMemo, I simply define the "person" object outside of the component. which fix the issue of unnecessary rerender for reference changing of props

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

let person = { fname: "mahabub", lname: "shaon" };
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  console.log("rendering parent");

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setState(state + 1)}>click to render</button>
      <Child person={person} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Child.js

```
import React from "react";

function Child({ person }) {
  console.log("rendering child");
  return (
    <h1>
      {person.fname} {person.lname}
    </h1>
  );
}
export default React.memo(Child);
```

Is it ok or any drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: With the problem, that you can only have one instance of the component, or the data being the same across all.